# register_nav_menus syntax error, unexpected identifier "register_nav_menus" in

Tags: themes

Hi i was following a video and i keep getting errors even when using the wordpress devleopers docs

here is my code

```
    register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'top-menu' => 'Top Menu Location' ,
      'mobile-menu' => 'Mobile Menu Location' 
     )
   );
```

### Thank you for taking the time to look and help!

Comment: Where did you add this code and how? did you manually add this code in `functions.php` or use a plugin, if you added the code manually, was it in a child theme?

Comment: i added it in functions.php also im trying to develop on localhost

Comment: Have you tried adding it inside of a callback of `init` or `after_setup_theme`?

Comment: no i will try now

Comment: no luck still throws erro

Comment: Can you show a more complete example of your code, where are you adding it, what is before and after. Not everything that's inside functions.php but a few lines before and after your code, just to get an idea. Or you can pate the whole thing in a code sharing platform and paste the link, could be easier to find, just make sure to not share any sensitive information, like creds and keys

Answer (score 0):

**In theme functions.php you just check this... I think it's may help you**

**In `demo_menus` function I use your code it works pretty well... I don't tell my code is good but I think this is best practice, we should try to best practice.**

```
function demo_menus(){
    $locations = array(
        'top-menu' => __( 'Top Menu Location', 'text-domain' ),
        'mobile-menu' => __( 'Mobile Menu Location', 'text-domain' )
    );
    register_nav_menus( $locations );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'demo_menus' );
```

### This is my localhost output

https://prnt.sc/qFXFDR1CHcj7

[image]